# Avoiding the warning 'The following features were omitted as they were not found in the scale.data slot for the SCT assay' in Seurat

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics, heatmap

I have a Seurat object

I want to plot a list of genes but I got a warning saying most of genes removed

I have tried with both ***my genes of interest*** and ***all variable genes*** but the results is very similar

Does this mean these genes are basically are not expressed in my data?

```
   > t$V1
  [1] "IGH"          "IGHV1-2"      "IGHV1-3"      "IGHV1-12"     "IGHV1-8"     
  [6] "IGHV1-14"     "IGHV1-17"     "IGHV1-18"     "IGHV1-24"     "IGHV1-45"    
 [11] "IGHV1-46"     "IGHV1-58"     "IGHV1-67"     "IGHV1-68"     "IGHV1-69"    
 [16] "IGHV1-69D"    "IGHV1-38-4"   "IGHV1-69-2"   "IGHV2-5"      "IGHV2-10"    
 [21] "IGHV2-26"     "IGHV2-70"     "IGHV2-70D"    "IGHV3-6"      "IGHV3-7"     
 [26] "IGHV3-9"      "IGHV3-11"     "IGHV3-13"     "IGHV3-15"     "IGHV3-16"    
 [31] "IGHV3-19"     "IGHV3-20"     "IGHV3-21"     "IGHV3-22"     "IGHV3-23"    
 [36] "IGHV3-25"     "IGHV3-29"     "IGHV3-30"     "IGHV3-30-2"   "IGHV3-30-3"  
 [41] "IGHV3-30-5"   "IGHV3-32"     "IGHV3-33"     "IGHV3-33-2"   "IGHV3-35"    
 [46] "IGHV3-36"     "IGHV3-37"     "IGHV3-38"     "IGHV3-41"     "IGHV3-42"    
 [51] "IGHV3-43"     "IGHV3-43D"    "IGHV3-47"     "IGHV3-48"     "IGHV3-49"    
 [56] "IGHV3-50"     "IGHV3-52"     "IGHV3-53"     "IGHV3-54"     "IGHV3-57"    
 [61] "IGHV3-60"     "IGHV3-62"     "IGHV3-63"     "IGHV3-64"     "IGHV3-65"    
 [66] "IGHV3-66"     "IGHV3-71"     "IGHV3-72"     "IGHV3-73"     "IGHV3-74"    
 [71] "IGHV3-75"     "IGHV3-76"     "IGHV3-79"     "IGHV3-38-3"   "IGHV3-69-1"  
 [76] "IGHV4-4"      "IGHV4-28"     "IGHV4-30-1"   "IGHV4-30-2"   "IGHV4-30-4"  
 [81] "IGHV4-31"     "IGHV4-34"     "IGHV4-39"     "IGHV4-55"     "IGHV4-59"    
 [86] "IGHV4-61"     "IGHV4-80"     "IGHV4-38-2"   "IGHV5-51"     "IGHV5-78"    
 [91] "IGHV5-10-1"   "IGHV6-1"      "IGHV7-4-1"    "IGHV7-40"     "IGHV7-27"    
 [96] "IGHV7-56"     "IGHV7-34-1"   "IGHV7-81"     "IGHVII-1-1"   "IGHVII-15-1" 
[101] "IGHVII-20-1"  "IGHVII-22-1"  "IGHVII-26-2"  "IGHVII-28-1"  "IGHVII-30-1" 
[106] "IGHVII-30-21" "IGHVII-31-1"  "IGHVII-33-1"  "IGHVII-40-1"  "IGHVII-43-1" 
[111] "IGHVII-44-2"  "IGHVII-46-1"  "IGHVII-49-1"  "IGHVII-51-2"  "IGHVII-53-1" 
[116] "IGHVII-60-1"  "IGHVII-62-1"  "IGHVII-65-1"  "IGHVII-67-1"  "IGHVII-74-1" 
[121] "IGHVII-78-1"  "IGHVIII-2-1"  "IGHVIII-5-1"  "IGHVIII-5-2"  "IGHVIII-11-1"
[126] "IGHVIII-13-1" "IGHVIII-16-1" "IGHVIII-22-2" "IGHVIII-25-1" "IGHVIII-26-1"
[131] "IGHVIII-38-1" "IGHVIII-44"   "IGHVIII-47-1" "IGHV8-51-1"   "IGHVIII-67-2"
[136] "IGHVIII-67-3" "IGHVIII-67-4" "IGHVIII-76-1" "IGHVIII-82"   "IGHVIV-44-1" 
[141] "IGHD1-1"      "IGHD1-7"      "IGHD1-14"     "IGHD1-20"     "IGHD1-26"    
[146] "IGHD2-2"      "IGHD2-8"      "IGHD2-15"     "IGHD2-21"     "IGHD3-3"     
[151] "IGHD3-9"      "IGHD3-10"     "IGHD3-16"     "IGHD3-22"     "IGHD4-4"     
[156] "IGHD4-11"     "IGHD4-17"     "IGHD4-23"     "IGHD5-5"      "IGHD5-12"    
[161] "IGHD5-18"     "IGHD5-24"     "IGHD6-6"      "IGHD6-13"     "IGHD6-19"    
[166] "IGHD6-25"     "IGHD7-27"     "IGHJ1"        "IGHJ1P"       "IGHJ2"       
[171] "IGHJ2P"       "IGHJ3"        "IGHJ3P"       "IGHJ4"        "IGHJ5"       
[176] "IGHJ6"        "IGHA1"        "IGHA2"        "IGHG1"        "IGHG2"       
[181] "IGHG3"        "IGHG4"        "IGHGP"        "IGHD"         "IGHE"        
[186] "IGHEP1"       "IGHM"        
> pbmc=ScaleData(
+     pbmc,
+     features = t$V1)
Centering and scaling data matrix
  |================================================================================| 100%
> DoHeatmap(pbmc,t$V1,group.by = "Condition")
Warning message:
In DoHeatmap(pbmc, t$V1, group.by = "Condition") :
  The following features were omitted as they were not found in the scale.data slot for the SCT assay: IGHEP1, IGHE, IGHJ6, IGHJ5, IGHJ4, IGHJ3P, IGHJ3, IGHJ2P, IGHJ2, IGHJ1P, IGHJ1, IGHD7-27, IGHD6-25, IGHD6-19, IGHD6-13, IGHD6-6, IGHD5-24, IGHD5-18, IGHD5-12, IGHD5-5, IGHD4-23, IGHD4-17, IGHD4-11, IGHD4-4, IGHD3-22, IGHD3-16, IGHD3-10, IGHD3-9, IGHD3-3, IGHD2-21, IGHD2-15, IGHD2-8, IGHD2-2, IGHD1-26, IGHD1-20, IGHD1-14, IGHD1-7, IGHD1-1, IGHVIV-44-1, IGHVIII-82, IGHVIII-76-1, IGHVIII-67-4, IGHVIII-67-3, IGHVIII-67-2, IGHV8-51-1, IGHVIII-47-1, IGHVIII-44, IGHVIII-38-1, IGHVIII-26-1, IGHVIII-25-1, IGHVIII-22-2, IGHVIII-16-1, IGHVIII-13-1, IGHVIII-11-1, IGHVIII-5-2, IGHVIII-5-1, IGHVIII-2-1, IGHVII-78-1, IGHVII-74-1, IGHVII-67-1, IGHVII-65-1, IGHVII-62-1, IGHVII-60-1, IGHVII-53-1, IGHVII-51-2, IGHVII-49-1, IGHVII-46-1, IGHVII-44-2, IGHVII-43-1, IGHVII-40-1, IGHVII-33-1, IGHVII-31-1, IGHVII-30-21, IGHVII-30-1, IGHVII-28-1, IGHVII-26-2, IGHVII-22-1, IGHVII-20-1, IGHVII-15-1, IGHVII-1-1, IGH [... truncated]
> pbmc=ScaleData(
+     pbmc,
+     features =rownames(pbmc))
Centering and scaling data matrix
  |================================================================================| 100%
> rm(pbmc)
> pbmc=readRDS("pbmc.rds")
> pbmc=ScaleData(
+     pbmc,
+     features =rownames(pbmc))
Centering and scaling data matrix
  |================================================================================| 100%
> DoHeatmap(pbmc,t$V1,group.by = "Condition")
Warning message:
In DoHeatmap(pbmc, t$V1, group.by = "Condition") :
  The following features were omitted as they were not found in the scale.data slot for the SCT assay: IGHEP1, IGHE, IGHJ6, IGHJ5, IGHJ4, IGHJ3P, IGHJ3, IGHJ2P, IGHJ2, IGHJ1P, IGHJ1, IGHD7-27, IGHD6-25, IGHD6-19, IGHD6-13, IGHD6-6, IGHD5-24, IGHD5-18, IGHD5-12, IGHD5-5, IGHD4-23, IGHD4-17, IGHD4-11, IGHD4-4, IGHD3-22, IGHD3-16, IGHD3-10, IGHD3-9, IGHD3-3, IGHD2-21, IGHD2-15, IGHD2-8, IGHD2-2, IGHD1-26, IGHD1-20, IGHD1-14, IGHD1-7, IGHD1-1, IGHVIV-44-1, IGHVIII-82, IGHVIII-76-1, IGHVIII-67-4, IGHVIII-67-3, IGHVIII-67-2, IGHV8-51-1, IGHVIII-47-1, IGHVIII-44, IGHVIII-38-1, IGHVIII-26-1, IGHVIII-25-1, IGHVIII-22-2, IGHVIII-16-1, IGHVIII-13-1, IGHVIII-11-1, IGHVIII-5-2, IGHVIII-5-1, IGHVIII-2-1, IGHVII-78-1, IGHVII-74-1, IGHVII-67-1, IGHVII-65-1, IGHVII-62-1, IGHVII-60-1, IGHVII-53-1, IGHVII-51-2, IGHVII-49-1, IGHVII-46-1, IGHVII-44-2, IGHVII-43-1, IGHVII-40-1, IGHVII-33-1, IGHVII-31-1, IGHVII-30-21, IGHVII-30-1, IGHVII-28-1, IGHVII-26-2, IGHVII-22-1, IGHVII-20-1, IGHVII-15-1, IGHVII-1-1, IGH [... truncated]
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify your genes of interest using the `features` parameter of the `ScaleData()` function. If this parameter is not specified, only "variable genes" are scaled and that makes sense, genes that do not demonstrate variability across conditions is not interesting in general. Anyhow, since the  `DoHeatmap()` would be looking at the "scaled data slot", it will not be able to find your genes of interest unless they show variation.

Comment: Thank you. I use sctranscform, I should scale my data before or after sctransform function?

Comment: From their vignette: `Note that this single command replaces NormalizeData(), ScaleData(), and FindVariableFeatures().`

Comment: I checked sctransform with or without scale data and the results was different

Comment: 1- Please do not edit your questions extensively, these questions meant to help future users too, now the answer and the question does not match. 2- Please read documentation associated with the functions/packages you use: `SCTransform()` doc says `return.only.var.genes: 
If set to TRUE the scale.data matrices in output assay are subset to contain only the variable genes; default is TRUE`. 3- Please show some effort, you will learn and develop faster if you learn by doing instead of asking questions on each step.